# Возможно ли соединить AvaloniaUI с MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, material-design

Разрабатывал проект на WPF с использованием [MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit), потом понял что необходимо иметь кроссплатформенность для данного проекта. Узнал про [AvaloniaUI](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia), почитал, понравилось. Но возник вопрос, возможно использовать AvaloniaUI с MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit?
И, если возможно, то как будет отображаться UI на разных платформах?

P.S. разрабатываю на Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Лучше спросить у них в gitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. Avalonia это всего лишь "XAML-based UI framework" и он не совместим с WPF.

Comment: А MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit конкретно под WPF сделана? Вообще нет вариантов? Просто видел что MaterialDesign ещё и под UWP сделанная, возможно можно сделать порт?

Comment: Скорее всего можно, только кто этим займётся?

Comment: Мне больше интересно как это будет отображаться на разных платформах. Так как в данный момент AvaloniaUI использует ресурсы отображения из ОС, а также костыль из Styling (Avalonia uses a CSS-like styling system)

Comment: Если AvaloniaUI станет востребованной, то найдутся такие люди которые сделают порт MaterialDesign)